# Java regex capturing groups indexes

Tags: java, regex

I have the following line,

```
typeName="ABC:xxxxx;";
```

I need to fetch the word `ABC`,

I wrote the following code snippet,

```
Pattern pattern4=Pattern.compile("(.*):");
matcher=pattern4.matcher(typeName);

String nameStr="";
if(matcher.find())
{
    nameStr=matcher.group(1);

}
```

So if I put `group(0)` I get `ABC:` but if I put `group(1)` it is `ABC`, so I want to know

1. What does this `0` and `1` mean? It will be better if anyone can explain me with good examples.
2. The regex pattern contains a `:` in it, so why `group(1)` result omits that? Does group 1 detects all the words inside the parenthesis?
3. So, if I put two more parenthesis such as, `\\s*(\d*)(.*)`: then, will be there two groups? `group(1)` will return the `(\d*)` part and `group(2)` return the `(.*)` part?

The code snippet was given in a purpose to clear my confusions. It is not the code I am dealing with. The code given above can be done with `String.split()` in a much easier way.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

### Capturing and grouping

*Capturing group* `(pattern)` creates a *group* that has *capturing* property.

A related one that you might often see (and use) is `(?:pattern)`, which creates a *group* without *capturing* property, hence named *non-capturing group*.

A group is usually used when you need to repeat a sequence of patterns, e.g. `(\.\w+)+`, or to specify where alternation should take effect, e.g. `^(0*1|1*0)$` (`^`, then `0*1` or `1*0`, then `$`) versus `^0*1|1*0$` (`^0*1` or `1*0$`).

A capturing group, apart from grouping, will also record the text matched by the pattern inside the capturing group `(pattern)`. Using your example, `(.*):`, `.*` matches `ABC` and `:` matches `:`, and since `.*` is inside capturing group `(.*)`, the text `ABC` is recorded for the capturing group 1.

### Group number

The whole pattern is *defined* to be group number 0.

Any capturing group in the pattern start indexing from 1. The indices are defined by the order of **the opening parentheses of the capturing groups**. As an example, here are **all** 5 capturing groups in the below pattern:

```
(group)(?:non-capturing-group)(g(?:ro|u)p( (nested)inside)(another)group)(?=assertion)
|     |                       |          | |      |      ||       |     |
1-----1                       |          | 4------4      |5-------5     |
                              |          3---------------3              |
                              2-----------------------------------------2
```

The group numbers are used in back-reference `\n` in pattern and `$n` in replacement string.

<sup>In other regex flavors (PCRE, Perl), they can also be used in *sub-routine calls*.</sup>

You can access the text matched by certain group with [`Matcher.group(int group)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)). The group numbers can be identified with the rule stated above.

<sup>In some regex flavors (PCRE, Perl), there is a *branch reset* feature which allows you to use **the same number** for **capturing groups in different branches of alternation**.</sup>

### Group name

From Java 7, you can define a [*named capturing group*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#groupname) `(?<name>pattern)`, and you can access the content matched with [`Matcher.group(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(java.lang.String)). The regex is longer, but the code is more meaningful, since it indicates what you are trying to match or extract with the regex.

The group names are used in back-reference `\k<name>` in pattern and `${name}` in replacement string.

Named capturing groups are still numbered with the same numbering scheme, so they can also be accessed via `Matcher.group(int group)`.

Internally, Java's implementation just maps from the name to the group number. Therefore, you cannot use the same name for 2 different capturing groups.

Comment: WOW! Thank you @nhahtdh for explaining non-capturing groups with how nesting group order works. I was stumped on how the group numbers worked until I finally read your explanation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 110):

### For The Rest Of Us

Here is a simple and clear example of how this works:
      `(     G1     )(  G2 )(    G3    )(  G4 )(  G5  )`
Regex:`([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\s]+)([a-zA-Z ]+)([\s]+)([0-9]+)`

String: `"!* UserName10 John Smith 01123 *!"`

```
group(0): UserName10 John Smith 01123
group(1): UserName10
group(2):  
group(3): John Smith
group(4):  
group(5): 01123
```

As you can see, I have created FIVE groups which are each enclosed in parentheses.

I included the !* and *! on either side to make it clearer. Note that none of those characters are in the RegEx and therefore will not be produced in the results. Group(0) merely gives you the entire matched string (all of my search criteria in one single line). Group 1 stops right before the first space because the space character was not included in the search criteria. Groups 2 and 4 are simply the white space, which in this case is literally a space character, but could also be a tab or a line feed etc. Group 3 includes the space because I put it in the search criteria ... etc.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: perfect example that is easy to understand for beginners. I've a doubt is this the same as reg ex grouping in python? or else is there any difference? i'm new to reg ex that's why I'm a bit confused in both languages.

Comment: This is not a valid Java regex: backslashes must be doubled.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Double backslash is due to the escape syntax in string literal. The actual regex syntax (i.e. if you print the string containing the regex to the console) doesn't require double backslash.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul If you were to copy and paste my regex string into actual java code using a competent IDE, the IDE would properly format the escape slashes as needed. But my Regex is technically and syntactically correct and it serves the main purpose which is to demonstrate the association between regex code and the results obtained (using a very specific example) ... lighten up a little... ☺

Comment: Funny and hits the bulls eye at the same time. Great work @MichaelSims

Answer (score 47):

Parenthesis `()` are used to enable grouping of regex phrases.

The `group(1)` contains the string that is between parenthesis `(.*)` so `.*` in this case

And `group(0)` contains whole matched string.

If you would have more groups (read `(...)` ) it would be put into groups with next indexes (2, 3 and so on).

Comment: So, I am correct that adding parenthesis is actually for creating groups?