# Want to check more string that read from file(regex)

Tags: java, regex

I'm very new with java right now I try to make a program to check DDL command(not connect with sql only accept file from the user and check they write command DDL right or wrong). 
First,I read file from the user
Second, I want to find string `create table name ()` and get string inside() to check from like

```
create table name(a int,b int)
```

so this is my code

```
 Input file from user 
 Read file in string str 
 String Ck_create="create table \\D[^;]+\\([^;](.*?)+[^;]+\\)";


 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Ck_create);
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

 if (matcher.find()) 
 {
  matcher.group()
  /*start to check line by line*/
  }
  else{/*error*/}
```

It work correctly but when I have create table more than one(like when create many tables in sql) program only care the first one that it met.It can't have many string group from a file like this

create table name
(
name int,
id int
)

create table table name2
(
lastname int,
wow int
)

Program will care only first table but I want to check string in table name2 too. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("REGEXP");
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry.I forgot to put all my code. Very thank you from your answer but I already have them. But i can't fix my problem

Comment: Are U sure that your regexp is correct? I spent several minutes trying to understand it how it behaves and then I gave up. You do not need to check for ; within braces but after the closing brace, do you? Post your test string as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate on single line:

```
    InputStream    fis = null;
    BufferedReader br  = null;
    String aFileLine;

    String fileName    = "the_file_name";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("create table \\D[^;]+\\([^;](.*?)+[^;]+\\)"); 
    Matcher mat = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        //  start to check line by line
        while ((aFileLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            mat = pattern.matcher(aFileLine);
            if (mat.find()) {
                String s = mat.group(1);
                // now you have your string in 's'
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File " + "'"+ fileName + "'" + "not found!!");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Done with the file
    try {
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    br = null;
    fis = null;
}
```

Comment: but if i check line by line I can't get string inside()

Comment: I edited my code `mat.group()` now is `mat.group(1)` that match with the string inside ().
Code takes single line in file and searches for string that match with `create table \\D[^;]+\\([^;](.*?)+[^;]+\\)`. Why you can't take the string?

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517689/confused-about-matcher-group-in-java-regex