# IndexOutOfBoundsException when using Matcher.find()

Tags: java, regex

This Java program showing me IndexOutOfBoundsException when it tries to invoke `group(1)`. If I replace `1` with `0` then the whole line is printed.. What do I have to do?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<abhi> abhinesh </abhi>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<abhi> abhinesh </abhi>");
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
else
    System.out.println("Not found");
```

Comment: What do you want `group(1)` to do/return? Do you know what group in regex is?

Comment: i want to print the text b/w the tags....

Comment: First of all, your input looks like XML so why are you using regex here instead of proper XML parser?

Comment: You don't have any regex groups (delimited by `()`).

Comment: i don't know much about that parser.i am familiar with java. thats why i am trying implement it in java.but if u say xml parser iam interested to do it.

Comment: Makoto if so why i am getting group(0) output.

Comment: `group(0)` represents the entire input string. You can read [the documentation for Matcher.group() here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this this regex:

```
<abhi>(.*)<\\/abhi>
```

The text you're after will be stored in the first capture group.

Example:

```
    String regex = "<abhi>(.*)<\\/abhi>";
    String input = "<abhi>foo</abhi>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

index starts at 0 so use `matcher.group(0)`

Edit : To match the text between tag use this regex `<abhi>(.*)<\\/abhi>`

Answer (score 1):

This post may shed more light on your question.
[Confused about Matcher Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517689/confused-about-matcher-group-in-java-regex).

In short you haven't defined any regular expression grouping to reference an alternate group. You only have the full matching string.

Below if you try adding a grouped regular expression to parse the xml you'll notice 0 has the full string, 1 has the begin tag, 2 has the value, and 3 has the end tag.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([a-z]+)>([a-z ]+)</([a-z]+)>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<abhi> abhinesh </abhi>");

if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));//<abhi> abhinesh </abhi>
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));//abhi
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));// abhinesh 
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3));//abhi
}else{
    System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

Comment: (_the capture groups are the things in parentheses_)