# confusion in java regex

Tags: java, regex

According to java.util.regex.Pattern documentation, `^` means negate, and also beginning of a line. How can I figure out, what `^` is being used for in any program?

This program from Thinking in Java (irrelevant to above question)

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class ReFlags {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^java]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(
        "java has regex\nJava has regex\n" +
        "JAVA has pretty good regular expressions\n" +
        "Regular expressions are in Java");
        while(m.find())
            System.out.print(m.group());
    }
}
```

gives output

```
 hs regex
 hs regex
 hs pretty good regulr expressions
Regulr expressions re in
```

pattern `^[java]` gives output `jJJ`.

pattern `(^java)`, `^(java)` and `^java` gives output `javaJavaJAVA`.

I understood the meaning of `[^java]`, but what do the other four patterns mean?
What could I do to get everything except the word java (case-insensitive) in the output?

Comment: `[^java]` is negative character class which means match anything except the ones listed in this class which is `j,a,v`

Comment: So, the output is as expected. In the first case it is a negation in a character class, and in the second it is a beginning of a line symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[^java]` - >  it matches any charcater but not of `j` or `v` or `a` . `[^..]` called negated character class. It matches all the chars except the one which was matched by the charcters present inside the negated charcater class.

`^java` -> it matches the string `java` present at the start of a line. You could print the match by `m.group(0)`.

`^(java)` -> it captures the string `java` present at the start of a line. You could print the match by `m.group(0)` and the chars inside first capturing group by `m.group(1)` where `m` is the `Matcher` class's object. So for this, you could get the string `java` from both `m.group(0)` and `m.group(1)`

`(^java)` -> same as the above, it captures the string `java` present at the start of a line.

Comment: is there any difference between matches and captures? i.e. between ^java and ^(java)?

Comment: @vicky96: Related read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517689/confused-about-matcher-group-in-java-regex Capturing group allows you extract text matched by some part of the expression. In the case of `^java` and `^(java)`, capturing group does not show its usefulness, since the capturing group captures exactly the same text as the whole expression.

Answer (score 1):

In a regex, `[…]` denotes a *character class*.  Character classes have their own mini-language: a different set of special characters applies, and they have different meanings.

Your best bet is to think of `^` in regexes as a beginning-of-line anchor.  *However*, in the context `[^abc]`, that's a negated character class, i.e. match any single character except `a` or `b` or `c`.

Another example of a difference is `-`.  In general, it's just a literal `-` character.  However, inside a character class, it defines a range.  (For example, `[a-z]` matches all ASCII lowercase letters.)