# Extract the matched string using reg-ex

Tags: java, regex

I've searched for questions relevant to Java regular expression and found out about the Pattern and Matcher classes to get you the group of text around the match criteria of the reg-ex.

However, my requirement is different. I wish to extract the actual text represented by the regular expression.

Example:

```
Input text: ABC 22. XYZ
Regular expression: (.*) [0-9]* (.*)
```

Using Pattern and Matcher classes (or any other way in Java), how can I get the text " 22. "? This is the text the regular expression represents.

Comment: No, it is not. The regular expression you gave matches the *whole* string, not just the `␠22.␠` part of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517689/confused-about-matcher-group-in-java-regex

Comment: @amrut:  Do you mean to ask how you can get `22.` using the `(.*) [0-9]* (.*)` pattern with Matcher/Patern classes? That is not possible because you need a dot as well after the digits and another capturing group around that subpattern (see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tU0fW2/3) and [code demo](http://ideone.com/ed1Xbt)). Note that you can get it with [`[0-9]+[.]` pattern using `Matcher#find()`](http://ideone.com/nWNsXk).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes. I missed the dot.

Comment: Impressive response time, mate! :)

Comment: I was on a hiatus :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **capturing groups** are off.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile ("(\\d+\\.?)");
Matcher m = p.matcher ("ABC 22. XYZ");
if (m.find ()) {
  System.out.println  (m.group (1));
}
```

With `(` and `)` you define *capturing groups* you can later retrieve from the matcher by group index. Group 0 is the whole match always.

Comment: No need for a group here. You might as well use `"\\d+\\.?"` and get the value using `m.group(0)`. So, the point is not the capturing group at all, but the dot that you made optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following regular expression<sup>1</sup>:

```
.*?(\s*\d+\.\s+).*
```

Using some graphical tool<sup>2</sup>, you can see where are the groups in the regular expression, i.e.:

[image: Imgur]

To extract that group, in Java you do something like the following:

```java
String input = "ABC 22. XYZ";

System.out.println(
    input.replaceAll(".*?(\\s*\\d+\\.\\s+).*", "$1")
);  // prints " 22. "
```

Where `$1` is replaced by `group #1`.

---

*Notes*

1. Explanation of the regular expression:

   ```
   NODE         EXPLANATION
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
     .*?        any character except \n (0 or more times
                (matching the least amount possible))
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
     (          group and capture to \1:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
       \s*        whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                  or more times (matching the most amount
                  possible))
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
       \d+        digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                  the most amount possible))
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
       \.         '.'
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
       \s+        whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                  or more times (matching the most amount
                  possible))
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
     )          end of \1
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
     .*         any character except \n (0 or more times
                (matching the most amount possible))
   ```
2. The tool where the screenshot was obtained is [Regexper](http://regexper.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Your input has a dot after "22", but your regex does not account for that.

If there's just one number in your input, you can extract it like this:

```
String number = input.replaceAll(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1");
```

This regex matches (the first) number (any length) anywhere in the input, regardless of the rest of the input is.