# How can I check if ArrayMap.keySet() contains a certain variable + Regex?

Tags: java, android, regex, contains

I have an `ArrayMap`, of which the `keys` are something like `tag - randomWord`. I want to check if the `tag` part of the key matches a certain variable.

I have tried messing around with `Patterns`, but to no success. The only way I can get this working at this moment, is iterating through all the keys in a `for` loop, then splitting the key on `' - '`, and getting the first value from that, to compare to my variable.

```
for (String s : testArray) {
    if ((s.split("(\\s)(-)(\\s)(.*)")[0]).equals(variableA)) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

This seems very devious to me, especially since I only need to know if the `keySet` *contains* the variable, that's all I'm interested in. I was thinking about using the `contains()` method, and put in `(variableA + "(\\s)(-)(\\s)(.*)")`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to use the `.contains()` method for this case, or do I have to loop the keys manually?

Comment: Try `.matches(".*" + Pattern.quote(variableA) + "\\s-\\s.*")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That would only work when iterating manually, correct?

Comment: No idea, the point is that you can only use a regex with matches, not with contains.

Comment: Interestingly, ArrayMap internally organizes the keys in natural order, this should allow you to do a simple binary prefix search on all the elements...

Answer (score 1):

You should split these tasks into two steps - first extract the tag, then compare it. Your code should look something like this:

```
for (String s : testArray) {
  if (arrayMap. keySet().contains(extractTag(s)) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

Notice that we've separated our concerns into two steps, making it easier to verify each step behaves correctly individually. So now the question is "How do we implement `extractTag()`?"

The `( )` symbols in a regular expression create a [group match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16517689/113632), which you can retrieve via [`Matcher.group()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-) - if you only care about `tag` you could use a `Pattern` like so:

```
"(\\S+)\\s-\\s.*"
```

In which case your `extractTag()` method would look like:

```
private static final Pattern TAG_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)\\s-\\s.*");
private static String extractTag(String s) {
  Matcher m = TAG_PATTERN.matcher(s);
  if (m.matches()) {
    return m.group(1);
  }
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(
    "'" + s + "' didn't match " TAG_PATTERN.pattern());
}
```

If you'd rather use `String.split()` you just need to define a regular expression that matches the delimiter, in this case `-`; you could use the following regular expression in a `split()` call:

```
"\\s-\\s"
```

It's often a good idea to use `+` after `\\s` to support one or more spaces, but it depends on what inputs you need to process. If you know it's always exactly one-space-followed-by-one-dash-followed-by-one-space, you could just split on:

```
" - "
```

In which case your `extractTag()` method would look like:

```
private static String extractTag(String s) {
  String[] parts = s.split(" - ");
  if (parts.length > 1) {
    return s[0];
  }
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not extract tag from '" + s + "'");
}
```