# Regex to extract 4-digit number from a String - Android

Tags: android, regex

I need to extract a 4-digit number from a string:

e.g "Your otp for the login is 7832. This code will expire at 12:43:09PM" from SMS in Android

I want to extract 7832 or any 4-digit code that comes within the string. I ensure that there will be only one 4-digit code in the string.

Please help me. I trying to use patterns like:

```
str.matches(".*\\\\d+.*");
```

But I'm not able to understand regexes much.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
String data = "Your otp for the login is 7832. This code will expire at 12:43:09PM";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4})");

//   \d is for a digit 
//   {} is the number of digits here 4.

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
String val = "";
if (matcher.find()) {        
    val = matcher.group(0);  // 4 digit number
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. What does matcher.group(1) means. What does "1" symbolizes here ?

Comment: for details refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517689/confused-about-matcher-group-in-java-regex

Comment: Would there be a problem if there are more than one occurrence of any 4 digit number. It is likely to have like the "year" in case a date arrives like 21-01-2019.

Comment: why 1? I had to use 0 for this to work

Answer (score 10):

Do:

```
\b\d{4}\b
```

- `\b` matches word boundary
- `\d{4}` matches 4 digits

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UCWEDU/1)