# Is there a more efficient way to search for a keyword within a sentence without knowing the keyword before compile?

Tags: java, search

I'm a 2nd year CS student and I wrote a program that connects to an IRC client and sniffs lines waiting for the user to ask "What is @TWITTERHANDLE tweeting about?"

The program sniffs for the keyword "tweeting" and then runs a method that will look for the twitter handle using the entire input line.

The problem is, I understand how to look for a keyword if I know what the keyword is going to be before I compile, but the keyword in this case could be any twitter handle so I'm not sure what the best method in searching for it would be.

I tried the following: inputLine.substring(i + 1, inputLine.indexOf(" ")); But it would use the first space in the inputLine as the second index giving me an IndexOutOfBounds exception.

An example of an input line is the following

```
:TWalk!46774664@gateway/web/freenode/ip.11.222.33.444 PRIVMSG #irchacks :What is @TWalkBot tweeting about right now?
```

And this is the code that I have that will actually grab the twitter handle.

```
/** This method parses the inputLine and returns the Twitter Handle */
    public String getTwitterHandle(String inputLine) {

        boolean firstAt = true;
        char currentChar, tempChar;

        for (int i = 0; i < inputLine.length(); i++) {

            currentChar = inputLine.charAt(i);

            if (currentChar == '@' && firstAt == false) {

                for (int j = i; j < inputLine.length(); j++) {

                    tempChar = inputLine.charAt(j);

                    if (tempChar == ' ') {

                        return inputLine.substring(i + 1, j);

                    }

                }

            }

            else if (currentChar == '@' && firstAt == true) {

                firstAt = false;
            }

        }

        return "User Not Found";
    }
```

While this code DOES work, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this and if so, what should I look at changing?

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: This may better fit at [codereview.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use REGEX to make it simple & accurate:

```
public class RegExPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test1 = "What is @TWITTERHANDLE tweeting about?";
        String test2 = ":TWalk!46774664@gateway/web/freenode/ip.11.222.33.444 PRIVMSG #irchacks :What is @TWalkBot tweeting about right now?";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*@(\\w+).*tweeting.*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test1);
        if(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //Sysouts TWITTERHANDLE
        }

        matcher = pattern.matcher(test2);
        if(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //Sysouts TWalkBot
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation on the REGEX**

> `.*@(\\w+).*tweeting.*`
>   
> `.*@` - Greedy pattern matches string until last occurrence of @ symbol
>   
> `(\\w+)` - Creates Group 1, followed by @ symbol, which is our target here, looking for word character of length 1 or more
>   
> `.*tweeting.*` - Looks for tweeting word to occur following Group 1, the first greedy `.*` pattern is used again to account for any character between Group 1 and tweeting, and second one is for any trailing characters after tweeting.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain exactly what the Matcher and Pattern do? I’m having trouble understanding what that pattern means.

Comment: These are good tutorials - [Linkk1](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/08/java-regex-tutorial/) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517689/confused-about-matcher-group-in-java-regex)  I found on internet, which will give you headstart. Go through it, and let me know if you still have questions.